# How to use header file <xmmintrin.h> with Yocto-generated SDK?

Tags: header-files, yocto, clang++, toolchain

I have an issue with a Yocto-generated SDK: the header file xmmintrin.h is not found when trying to compile with the SDK. Example:

```
$ echo '#include <xmmintrin.h>' > t.cpp
$ $CXX $CXXFLAGS -no-canonical-prefixes -c t.cpp
t.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'xmmintrin.h' file not found
```

$CXX points to the SDK's clang++.

The verbose output is:

```
$ $CXX $CXXFLAGS -no-canonical-prefixes -c t.cpp -v

clang version 6.0.0 (git://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang.git ff0c0d8ab3e316bb6e2741fedb3b545e198eab7a) (git://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm.git 089d4c0c490687db6c75f1d074e99c4d42936a50)
Target: x86_64-poky-linux-musl
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux-musl
Found candidate GCC installation: /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/usr/lib//x86_64-poky-linux-musl/7.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux-musl/7.3.0
Selected GCC installation: /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/usr/lib//x86_64-poky-linux-musl/7.3.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux-musl/x86_64-poky-linux-musl-clang++" -cc1 -triple x86_64-poky-linux-musl -emit-obj -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name t.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mthread-model posix -fmath-errno -mfpmath sse -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu core2 -target-feature +sse3 -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -coverage-notes-file /home/kamo7631/t.gcno -rpokyurce-dir /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/lib/clang/6.0.0 -isysroot /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl -internal-isystem /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/lib/clang/6.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/include -internal-externc-isystem /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/usr/include -O2 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/kamo7631 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 132 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o t.o -x c++ t.cpp
clang -cc1 version 6.0.0 based upon LLVM 6.0.0 default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/lib/clang/6.0.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/usr/include/c++/v1
 /opt/poky-tiny/2.4.2/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl/usr/include
End of search list.
t.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'xmmintrin.h' file not found
#include <xmmintrin.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

The header file is present as sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/clang/6.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h, but is not found anywhere in sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux-musl (the target sysroot).

What do I have to change in order to be able to use this and other header files from the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post output of

```
$CLANGCXX $CXXFLAGS -no-canonical-prefixes -c t.cpp -v
```

I think the problem is a bug in SDK where compiler include paths are looking for
compiler headers but in wrong directory. Maybe its pointing to sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/lib/clang/6.0.0/include

you can try to add -I ${OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/clang/6.0.0/include to your compiler cmdline. also make sure you have sources the SDK environment script which is at the top of SDK install dir, its name starts like this "environment-setup-"

Comment: I have added -I${OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/clang/6.0.0/include to the compiler call variables in my own meta-environment.bbappend. Thank you!